# Is all research needed to reach top tier upgrades in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Do I have to get all of the possible Zerg and Protoss research in every mission of the Wings of Liberty campaign in order to get the top-level upgrades?  I've missed a couple points and I'm wondering if I should go back and redo those missions to max out my research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not. About 2/3ds of the way through (and especially after the Zeratul missions which give you a great deal of research poitns) you cap out on both, and you start being able to "sell" extra research to the Moebius Foundation for 10k each.